# Is visualization with Druid and Superset only possible for time-series data?

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, apache-superset, druid

When I connect Druid and Superset, can I use the data I have only for time-series charts? Or can I use it for other charts as well? (deck.gl Scatterplot, Mapbox etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Through SQLAlchemy, Superset generates database-specific queries in the no-code, Explore interface. As long as the database is well supported in Superset, all chart types should work!